# How to manage ResolvePackageNotFound - pytorch=1.0.0 error with conda

Tags: pytorch, dependencies, conda

I want to use this [github code](https://github.com/sefibk/KernelGAN) for a project. It has a .yml document so I use conda to download all the dependencies.

```
KernelGAN.yml : 

name: KernelGanTest
channels:
  - pytorch
  - defaults

dependencies:
  - python=3.6.6
  - cudatoolkit>=9.0
  - numpy=1.15.1
  - pytorch=1.0.0
  - tensorflow-gpu=1.12.0
  - tqdm=4.26.0
  - scipy=1.1.0
  - pillow=5.2.0
  - opencv=3.4.2
  - matplotlib=2.2.3
```

I run this code in Anaconda Prompt

`conda env create -f KernelGan.yml`

But it can't find pytorch = 1.0.0

> conda env create -f KernelGan.yml
>
> (repodata.json): done Solving environment: failed
>
> ResolvePackageNotFound:
>
> - pytorch=1.0.0

I'm using windows.
I updated Conda.
I tried to remove pytorch from my dependencies and to pip install it but it didn't worked.

I'm sorry if the answer is obvious but I really can't find the solution.

Does someone knows how to deal with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the [files list](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch/files?sort=time&sort_order=asc) for pytorch, you will see that the oldes version still in the channel seems to be 1.5.1.

You can also see that if you do `conda search -c pytorch pytorch`

As that contradicts the official [docs](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/), I would suggest that you raise it as an issue [on github](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues).

As a workaround, you could try

`pip install --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/ torch==1.0.0`

or you manually download and install the whl file https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! pip install --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/ pytorch==1.0.0 
didn't worked :
Looking in indexes: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytorch==1.0.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytorch==1.0.0

I'll investigate the last solution :)

Comment: My bad, fixed the command